# Using a base class but defining a property

Tags: python, tree, python-3.x

I have designed a Python `TreeNodeBase` class, so all tree nodes I implement can inherit from this. However, due to the laziness inherent in a lot of trees, I would like some fields to be properties (using the `@property` decorator) instead.

But doing so, the base class will raise `AttributeError` whenever it tries to set a field, when I call `super().__init__()`. The way I'm resolving this now is to ignore the `AttributeError`. Is this a good idea, and is there a standard approach to this problem?

```
from contextlib import suppress

class TreeNodeBase:
    def __init__(self, value, edge_value=None, children=None, parent=None, tree=None):
        with suppress(AttributeError):
            self.value = value
        with suppress(AttributeError):
            self.edge_value = edge_value
        with suppress(AttributeError):
            self.children = children
        with suppress(AttributeError):
            self.parent = parent
        self.tree = tree

    def get_child(self, edge_value):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Comment: Could you provide an example that causes the error you mention (if `contextlib.suppress` is removed)? If the child class defines a `@property` for e.g. `edge_value`, the setter will get called by the base class `__init__`.

Answer (score 2):

You solution does look a bit fragile, but I can't help that without seeing more of the hierarchy. The way I'd approach this is to add `value=None` to your argument function header, and then do this for each attribute:

```
if value is not None:
    self.value = value
```

That way the inheriting classes can signal that they don't want the attribute initialised by just leaving the attribute out of the `__init__` args, or passing `None` (this won't work if you actually want None as a value. You'd have to find another placeholder). That way, the system will be a bit more flexible, and there will not be any bad consequences caused by trying to initialise an attribute which is not meant to be initialised.

Comment: Good idea, but I do indeed need `None` for parameter values. Using some other placeholder, would work but feels rather strange. Also tried `has_value` which also works but adds a lot of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

That approach (silencing exceptions) looks like trouble.

In general I'd say that @matsjoyce is right, why do you want to set
unsettable, by virtue of being properties, attributes?  Also, setting
variables like this isn't very much trouble, you can just do that each
derived class instead and be done with it.

Now certainly, if you create nodes with defaults and then choose a class
which implements them as read-only properties instead, then it makes a
bit of sense to just disregard that information at the calling site and
just try to set everything.

However, let's at least look at four options.

First, you can make setters, which plain ignore any set value.  That way
the init function is clean, but you might run into bugs because this
behaviour is silent.  You could then set a flag in the init function,
which will suppress throwing a regular `AttributeError`, which you will
throw yourself in every setter normally.  That way you have the best of
both worlds.

The next would be to use `**kwargs` and not set any attributes not
mentioned in that dictionary.  Again, this way you'd have to be aware of
what a class can actually do and then omit invalid attributes.

You could also remove invalid arguments in the init function of derived
classes, or simply not pass them on.

Lastly, you could look up whether the attributes are available in the
`__dict__` of the object.  For that you'd have to initialise them (to
`None` or so) in the init function of the derived class.